# Customize "Stage this hunk" prompt in `git add -p`?

Tags: git, git-add

I've started reusing `git add -p` as a building block for other situations where it's nice to have an interactive interface to accept/reject/edit changes.

It's profoundly useful! The biggest win for me is that I've implemented partial save/load in my text editor on top of this. But it also helps with other miscellaneous tasks.

The exact implementation doesn't matter, but here's one minimal way to do it (create a temporary directory, initialize it as a Git repo, copy one version of the file into it, stage it, copy the other version of the file over it, `git add --patch` to go through the differences, throw away anything that didn't stage, and that's our result):

```bash
#!/bin/sh -
cleanup()
{
    case ${directory+x} in x)
        rm -rf "$directory"
    esac
}
output=${3-"$1"}
directory=`mktemp -d` &&
trap cleanup EXIT TERM INT HUP &&
(cd "$directory" && git init --quiet) &&
cp "$1" "$directory"/contents &&
(cd "$directory" && git add contents) &&
cp "$2" "$directory"/contents &&
(cd "$directory" && git add --patch contents) &&
(cd "$directory" && git checkout --quiet contents) &&
cp "$directory"/contents "$output"
```

Anyway, there's just one UI/UX touch this needs: to change the "Stage this hunk [...]?" prompt to whatever is more appropriate for the use-case. For example, for partial save in my editor, I'd like it to say "Save this hunk [...]?"

Right now, I only know how to pick between one of the other built-in prompts by slightly re-arranging the script (for example, `git reset -p` will ask "Unstage this hunk [...]?"; `git checkout -p` will ask "Discard this hunk from worktree [...]?", and `git stash -p` will ask "Stash this hunk [...]?").

I'm hoping we can do something better than piping through a particularly cautious `sed`, but that's a low I'm willing to stoop to if we can get it really robust and preserve fancy color output (and not break diff-enhancing helpers like git-delta).

Comment: It looks like the actual strings are hardcoded in one of the Perl files that make up the Git CLI... on the one system I checked, that's in `my %patch_update_prompt_modes` which starts at line 1433 in `/usr/lib/git-core/git-add--interactive`.

Comment: have a look at `git gui`: it provides a (imho) very convenient way to view and edit your patch -- you can do it chunk by chunk or line by line, at your convenience

Comment: @LeGEC thanks, though that sounds like it's addressing a different... direction of need than what I'm after here. I am not looking for a better UI for Git/patches, I am looking to reuse the Git CLI which I'm already fully satisfied with in a variety of other situations beyond Git/patches, as a building block in other code/tools, etc. (Also, I'm pretty particular about my UI/UX, and so far I've never seen a GUI that's nice enough **for me** unless it has exceptional **malleability** - unless it goes out of its way to make it really easy for me to hook into it, extend it, and change it deeply.)